# How to assign date quarters to integer values

Tags: r

I have a dataset that includes a date column consisting of the following:

```
date
0.25
0.50
0.75
1.00
1.25
1.50
1.75
2.00
2.25
(etc)
```

This indicates yearly quarters.
What I am trying to do is convert each quarter to have a corresponding value, 0.25 being the first quarter, 0.50 being the second and so on.

What the outcome would look like is a new column with values 1:4 for each year's quarter.
Something like:

```
date     quarter
0.25      1
0.50      2
0.75      3
1.00      4
1.25      1
1.50      2
1.75      3
2.00      4
(etc)
```

I know this could be done a long way (the dreaded for loop) but I am hoping a more succinct bit of code is possible. Thanks

Comment: It is always useful to provide some reproducible data.

Comment: However, you could convert the date column to a character variable using `as.character()`. Then use `grep()` or `grepl()` to identify the rows containing .00, .25, .5, .75 and assign a new variable Based on this conditions. Afterwars you can convert `date` back to a numeric variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
date <- c(.25,.5,.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2)

quarter <- (date-floor(date))/.25
quarter <- ifelse(quarter == 0, 4, quarter)
quarter
[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

With `(date-floor(date))` you keep just the decimal places of the number. Then you divide by `.25` to see what quarter it is. And finally replacing zero by four.

EDIT

I see my answer has same logic as the other one. I keep it anyway because the explanation might help.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(quarter = date - floor(date), 
         quarter = case_when(quarter == 0.25 ~ 1,
                             quarter == 0.50 ~ 2,
                             quarter == 0.75 ~ 3,
                             TRUE ~ 4)) 

#>   date quarter
#> 1 0.25       1
#> 2 0.50       2
#> 3 0.75       3
#> 4 1.00       4
#> 5 1.25       1
#> 6 1.50       2
#> 7 1.75       3
#> 8 2.00       4
#> 9 2.25       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the date by 4 to give a whole number value and subtract 1 giving 0, 1, 2, ... .  Then take the remainder after dividing by 4 and add 1.  Of the solutions we present below this one is the shortest and the solutions in this section are equally general and do not require that the quarters be consecutive or start with the first quarter.

Note that x %% 4 means the remainder after dividing by 4 and x %% 1 is the remainder after dividing by 1, i.e. the fractional part.

```
transform(DF, quarter = (4 * date - 1) %% 4 + 1)
```

An alternative is to convert to a factor and take the integer levels

```
transform(DF, quarter = as.integer(factor((date - 0.25) %% 1)))
```

Yet another approach is to use the yearqtr class in zoo. It represents year/quarter dates internally using year plus 0, 1/4, 1/2 and 3/4 for the 4 quarters.

```
library(zoo)
transform(DF, quarter = cycle(as.yearqtr(date - 0.25)))
```

Although a bit laborious this one is quite simple:

```
transform(DF, quarter = match(date %% 1, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.00)))
```

### Consecutive quarters

If we knew that the quarters were consecutive and start with the first quarter we could repeat the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4 to the required length like this.  While less general it is very simple.

```
transform(DF, quarter = rep(1:4, length = nrow(DF)))
```

Another way if we knew that that the quarters were consecutive and start with the first quarter is to convert `date` to a ts series and use cycle.

```
transform(DF, quarter = c(cycle(ts(date, freq = 4))))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
DF <-
structure(list(date = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 
2, 2.25)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```